# Submit form in Java

Tags: javascript, java, forms

I need to get output of form of web page in Java, but there is a problem. My code is below.

```
    String query = "input=mysearch";
    String charset = "UTF-8";
    String str;


    URLConnection connection = new URL("http://www.webpage.com/").openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true); // Triggers POST method.
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=" + charset);
    connection.getOutputStream().write(query.getBytes(charset));
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")
    );


    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(str); 
    }
```

Problem is in that submit button on web page looks like this

```
 <a href="javascript:document.forms[0].submit();" type="submit" class="btn" id="search-btn"><i class="demo-icon icon-search"></i></a>
```

So it is not submitted. Instead of this is submitted different button, which belongs to different form.

```
 <input type="submit" name="btnAdmin" value="Submit" id="btnAdmin" class="button" style="width:100%;" />
```

Any suggestion how should I submit right form?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) from Apache. It massively simplifies this for you. Below is how you might decide to submit a form (mostly taken from the tutorial section of the website):

```
List<NameValuePair> formparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1", "value1"));
formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param2", "value2"));
UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formparams, Consts.UTF_8);
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://website.com/form_action_attribute.php");
httppost.setEntity(entity);
```

You can capture the response and stuff too if you need to do that.

Comment: Actually, it is not a http post submit, but just a javascript function that takes values from a textbox..:-/ Any possibility how to call this javacript function in Java?